# Windows Phone XML Parsing - '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character or Unexpected end of file has occurred

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I'm writing a program for Windows Phone in VB.net that downloads an XML file, reads the data, then outputs it to a textbox. Then, every 3 seconds, it repeats the process. The problem I have, is when the length of the XML file changes, I get

> '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character

if the file got smaller and

> Unexpected end of file has occurred

if it got larger. The code being executed on launch and every 3 seconds is the following:

```
    Dim doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring)
```

where xmlstring is a string that contains the entire xml document's contents. What should I do?

-update-

Here's all of the code.

```
    Imports System.Xml.Linq
    Partial Public Class MainPage
Inherits PhoneApplicationPage
Private WithEvents dt As System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
Private wbcl As New WebClient 'WebClient for downloading XML as string
' Constructor
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
    DataContext = App.ViewModel

End Sub
' Load data for the ViewModel Items
Private Sub MainPage_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    If Not App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded Then
        App.ViewModel.LoadData()
    End If
    AddHandler wbcl.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf cl_DownloadStringCompleted 'adds handler for download complete
    wbcl.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://www.copycatmusicracine.com/app/ccatnowplaying.xml?" + "time=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString)) 'downloads xml as string
    dt = New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer() 'creates timer
    dt.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 3000) ' dt_Tick every 3 seconds
    dt.Start() 'starts timer
End Sub
Private Sub dt_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles dt.Tick
    AddHandler wbcl.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf cl_DownloadStringCompleted 'adds handler for download complete
    wbcl.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://www.copycatmusicracine.com/app/ccatnowplaying.xml?" + "time=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString)) 'downloads xml as string
End Sub
Private Sub cl_DownloadStringCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim xmlstring As String = e.Result 'puts XML as string into a new variable
    Dim doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring) 'XML is parsed
    If doc.<song>.<title>.Value = "NULL" Then
        'Stuff to happen when song is not playing
    Else
        'Stuff to happen when song is playing
    End If
    End Sub
    End Class
```

Like I said, the code works the first time, but after it's launched, when the XML file changes, it gives me an error.

Comment: How are you reading the file into the string?

Comment: I use a webclient to download the XML file as a string. When the file is completely downloaded, it performs the XDocument Parse thing. It always works the first time, but when the XML file changes, it gives me one of the errors mentioned above.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code that you posted, so the problem would be where you create the string. Can you post your code where you download the data into the string?

Comment: Alright, I'm just going to post the entire project in the question so there's no confusion. Also, the error happens only after the XML file changes, so I'm going to have the file change every 30 seconds so that maybe it'll be easier to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: I'm not sure the WebClient is thread-safe. I'd suggest creating a new instance every time `dt_Tick` is called, rather than re-using the old one (which may still be downloading the data from the previous request)

Comment: Okay, thanks. That makes sense. I got everything working now.